# What do the negative/positive throttles in the DS3 trigger buttons do?

Tags: ps3, controllers, emulation

I have no idea what the difference between the five options of throttle. In whatever choice, only one button is triggerable even both two are assigned, be it's pressed slightly or held long.

[image: Emulator Picture]

The emulator in use is AntiMicro.

FYI: [Are questions asking about a feature of controller emulators on-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12545/95533)

Comment: At a guess, the negative throttle applies an artificial slowing effect to the rate of depression when you press the trigger, and the positive throttle applies an artificial speeding effect when you press the trigger. In essence, the emulator artificially slows down or speeds up your input from the trigger.

Comment: Then what do the half throttles do?

Comment: I'm guessing that it throttles at half the rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AntiMicro is not properly recognizing your controllers.

I believe the question was already answered here:

https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro/issues/164